# Solaris prstat - definition of “recent” time used in percentages

Tags: solaris, performance, monitoring, cpu

The man page for prstat (on Solaris 10 in my case) notes that that CPU % output is the "percentage of recent CPU time". I am trying to understand in more depth what "recent" means in this context - is it a defined amount of time prior to the sample, does it relate to the sampling interval, etc? Appreciate any insights, particularly with references to supporting documentation. I've searched but haven't been able to find a good answer. Thanks!

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

It may be slightly different in Solaris, but based on the Illumos source [here](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/prstat/prstat.c#L767), it looks like the value first displayed is since the process started and updates after that are since the last displayed value. The display updates every 5 seconds by default, but that can be specified.